# Streaming issue due to missing Adobe components in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, firefox, google-chrome, streaming, adobe

I know there are a couple of threads on hotstar.com not working in Ubuntu. I reached them and found the issue to be missing Adobe elements support with Ubuntu

> We use Adobe Flash Player and Adobe DRM & Adobe has stopped support
>   for Flash Player on Ubuntu, hence the issue.

I was checking how their streaming service works in Windows, but not in Ubuntu. This happened even when I use Google Chrome and Firefox within Ubuntu. Any work around possible ? Thanks.

Comment: Are you use Chrome or Chromium? I'm asking because Chrome being delivered with Pepper Flash *(which is latest Flash modified by Google)*. Also FYI Adobe is officially dropping support for Flash by 2020 *(almost 2 years left)*, so they have to migrate to another solution, e.g. the one Netflix are using. You can annoy them a bit, to hasten up their migration.

Comment: @Hi-Angel I have issues on both Chromium as well as Google Chrome. I really hope they are true to their word about " Working on it.."